# Theorem For Logic Reduction to LUT for FPGA

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, fpga

I would like to know if there is any theorem that states that any logic can be broken down and simplified such that we can encode that logic in the form of LUT that can be deployed in FPGA.

Comment: It's not clear to me. Are you asking for a proof that the universe of all possible combinatorial logic permutations can be mapped onto every possible LUT topology on every FPGA, past, present, or future, given sufficient numbers of them and unlimited routing?

Comment: well yes. Is there any theorem? Just like we have universal approximation theorem of neural networks.

Comment: Voting to close because this is clearly two widely different questions, and as such is outside of the standards for this Stackexchange.  Please *edit the question down* to one or the other (and ask the other, if you wish) -- I'll be happy to help.

Comment: @TimWescott I think the author is looking for mathematical intuition for limitation of logic decomposition for FPGA

Comment: Then they should edit their question down so that's all they're asking, and not ask for comments on the processor vs. FPGA debate.

Comment: @TimWescott What I am looking for is to know that if the logic can be broken down such that it can be executed by FPGA then why do we even use micro-controller and why not just FPGA because FPGA's are orders of magnitude faster. Now with the answer I understood that micro-controllers are good for handling sequential logic that cannot be decomposed to LUT hence FPGA's can't be used. This is why I asked for the theorem that can mathematically justify this. So I think my question was well targeted. Let me know if I still need to improve my question?

Comment: That is **two questions**, as I detailed.  This is Stackexchange.  If you have **two questions**, then you should **ask two questions**, you should not embed them into one.  And you embed a monstrously large assumption into your statement "because FPGA's are orders of magnitude faster" -- no, not always, which is why *that is a separate question* from "can you decompose all logic to LUTs".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, combinatorial logic can be represented as a look-up table. Just write out the truth table for the logic and there you go. Now, after a certain size it won't fit in the LUT resources available on a certain FPGA, or you will have other limits. Sequential logic cannot be represented directly using a LUT.

About replacing combinatorial logic / LUT with a microcontroller: it doesn't really make sense. They do not serve the same function. Perhaps you were told that microcontrollers just run a calculation? It's not that simple. They need to be able to execute a program, which combinational logic just cannot do; you need sequential logic.

Comment: Alright so FPGA is suited for combinatorial logic while microcontroller is suited for sequential logic right? Secondly the reason LUT cannot be utilized for sequential logic is because the space of representation of every possible sequence would be exponentially large right?

Comment: Also I didn't meant to say replace combinatorial logic with micro controller

Comment: @metron FPGAs don't just contain LUTs; they also contain flip flops and other stateful logic. You can absolutely implement stateful logic on an FPGA. You can even implement a microcontroller on an FPGA if you want.

Comment: @alex.forencich I see. this makes so much sense now. So my understanding that we dont implement sequential logic in FPGA due to logic space being exponentially large is correct or false? So simply, why dont we use FPGA instead of micro controller as FPGA's are much faster?

Comment: @metron There is a cost associated with using LUTs.  Advantage: they are reconfigurable.  Disadvantage: they are slow and inefficient.  You can fit a lot more logic on an ASIC and run it a lot faster with less power consumption.  However, making an ASIC is extremely expensive (millions of dollars).  Microcontrollers are designed to be small, cheap, and low power, hence they are usually also rather slow.  A microcontroller might be $1, while an equivalent FPGA might be $100+ and consume far more power.

Comment: @alex.forencich +1 for giving holistic intitution, on this! It makes so much sense now. I thought using LUT's make them faster but as you mentioned they make them slower and inefficient.